# Remove reverse values from a multidimentional array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a multidimensional array to draw sankey chart. But it doesn't support cycle values.  So i want to remove an array if it comes in reverse oerder. For eg:
if i have an array named,

```
var myArray = [['aaa','20'],['bbb','30'],['ccc','40'],['30','bbb']]
```

I want to get a result as follows:

```
var myArray = [['aaa','20'],['bbb','30'],['ccc','40']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter by checking the predecessors of the array.

```js
var array = [['aaa','20'],['bbb','30'],['ccc','40'],['30','bbb']],
    result = array.filter(function (a, i, aa) {
        return aa.slice(0, i).every(function (b) {
            return a[0] !== b[1] || a[1] !== b[0];
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For an arbitrary count of items, you could get a copy of the inner array, sort it and get a joined string of it and compare it with a hash table.

```js
var array = [["M", "A", 1], ["B", "G", 1], ["A", "M", 1], ["B", "C", 1]],
    result = array.filter(function (hash) {
        return function (a) {
            var t = a.slice().sort().join('|');
            return !hash[t] && (hash[t] = true);
        };
    }(Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how can i modify the code if three values are there in my array like; ["M","A",1],["B","G",1],["A","M",1],["B","C",1]

Comment: could the items be in any order?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you expected the first value to be a string and the second to be an integer, you could easily filter out "backwards" arrays by just checking to make sure the first value is not an integer:

```
function removeBackwardsArrays(values) {
    return !parseInt(values[0]);
}

var values = [['aaa','20'],['bbb','30'],['ccc','40'],['30','bbb']];

console.log(values.filter(removeBackwardsArrays));
```

Feel free to manipulate the filter based on whatever conditional you seem fit.